# How Close task in batch file

Tags: batch-file, task, kill

I've a Intranet with an asmx Page to do some works. I need to execute it, each day. I make a batch file, put it in task manager of my server. It's ok to run... But I add a part to kill this one after severals minutes and the problem is here.
This is my batch file... Where is my error... I use a label (ImportToDo) to create a task and ask it to kill

```
@echo off
start "ImportToDo" iexplore.exe http://MySrv:MyPort/interne/Import.asmx/Importation
Timeout /T 80 /NoBreak>NUL

taskkill /F /IM "ImportToDo" /T > nul
```

Thanks for yours helps

Comment: Check `tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq iexplore.exe" /fo csv /v`. The `"ImportToDo"` is not a valid  image name. Apply `taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe /T`.

Comment: "ImportToDo" is the title of the command prompt window that would have been shown if starting a console program. In your example it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my batch late in the day to be sure do not close IE of anotherone.
And I take solution odf JosefZ

```
taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe /T
```

It's Ok
Thanks